# Get azure container blob contents using powershell

Tags: powershell, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to get the azure container blob contents using Powershell.

**Code**

```
$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName abc -StorageAccountKey 'xxxx=='
$latestBuild = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $Ctx -Container jmeter -blob "Script\Load1"
if($latestBuild -ne $null)
{
    foreach($item in $latestBuild)
    { 
        Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob $item.name -Container jmeter -Destination C:\ -Context $Ctx -Force
    }
}
else
{
    write-host "Blob is empty !!!"
}
```

**Error**

```
Get-AzStorageBlob : Can not find blob 'Script\Load1' in container 'jmeter', or the blob type is unsupported.
At line:2 char:16
+ ... testBuild = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $Ctx -Container jmeter -blob " ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-AzStorageBlob], ResourceNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ResourceNotFoundException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageBlobCommand

Blob is empty !!!
```

There are two files present in the Load1 folder :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's not how it works, you have to do it differently:

```
Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $Ctx -Container jmeter -Prefix "Script/Load1"
```

or just:

```
Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $Ctx -Container jmeter -Blob "Script/Load1*"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-3.6.1

Comment: Now it goes to else part and it is not able to find files. Blob is empty !!!

Comment: The issue is I am using a backslash instead of forward. -blob Script/Load1*

Please correct your answer.